# Check for more than 1 running instance of powershell script launched using ".\scriptName.ps1"

Tags: powershell

The below thread explains how to check for more than 1 instance of a powershell script using `get-wmiobject win32_process`

[Assure only 1 instance of PowerShell Script is Running at any given Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969662/assure-only-1-instance-of-powershell-script-is-running-at-any-given-time)

For `get-wmiobject win32_process` to list a running powershell script, that script needs to be invoked using `powershell.exe scriptName.ps1`. How can I check for more than 1 instance of the script running where the script was invoked using `.\scriptName.ps1`?

Comment: Your `GWMI` call is the same as `Get-Process` essentially.  All it tells you is whether the `powershell.exe` process is running, not whether a specific script is running.

Comment: If I had to guess, what you really want is a Mutex...

Comment: On the contraty, GWMI allows me to see not only that the powershell.exe process is running but also shows me the exact commandline (i.e. with arguments), whereas Get-Process only shows me that the powershell.exe is running

Answer (score -1):

You could use the below and see if the result is > 1

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | select commandline | where {$_ -ilike "*scriptName.ps1*"} | measure).Count
```

Comment: That could work but has 2 problems: 1- If someone opens a powershell window and then runs the script from the cmd line, this won't detect it. 2 - If someone tries to edit it, by say typing `notepad scriptName.ps1`, you'll get a false positive.

Comment: Comparison operators are case-insensitive by default.  I'm really not sure why they made explicit operators for it

Comment: Get-WmiObject Win32_Process requires that one invoke a powershell script using "powershell.exe <scriptName>", like @zdan said